# SqlNotificationInfo returns SqlNotificationInfo.Options

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have this code, that works well for `Database1`, but for `Database2` only returns `SqlNotificationInfo.Options`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace SQLNotifications
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        //string connectionstring = @"Server=EEPERSIAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=RMS;User ID=sa;pwd=1";
        string connectionstring = @"Server=EEPERSIAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=RMS;User ID=sa;pwd=1";

        delegate void GridDelegate(DataTable table);

        SqlDependency dep;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlDependency.Start(connectionstring);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("لطفاً سرویس Service Broker نرم افزار SQL Server خود را فعال کنید ");                
            }

            UpdateGrid();
        }

        private void UpdateGrid()
        {

           string sql = "select Sales from dbo.Batch";

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))

            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    dep = new SqlDependency(cmd); //Passing Command to SQL dependency 

                    dep.OnChange += dep_OnChange;

                    using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        dt.Load(rdr);
                    }
                }
            }
            dataGridView1.Invoke(
                (GridDelegate)delegate(DataTable table)
                {
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = table; 
                }
                , dt);
        }
        private void dep_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Info==SqlNotificationInfo.AlreadyChanged)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("AlreadyChanged Accourd");
            }

            if (e.Info == SqlNotificationInfo.Alter)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Alter Accourd");
            }

            if (e.Info == SqlNotificationInfo.Delete)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Delete Accourd");
            }

            if (e.Info == SqlNotificationInfo.Drop)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Drop Accourd");
            }

            if (e.Info == SqlNotificationInfo.Error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error Accourd");
            }

            if (e.Info == SqlNotificationInfo.Expired)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Expired Accourd");
            }

            if (e.Info == SqlNotificationInfo.Insert)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Insert Accourd");
                UpdateGrid();
            }

            if (e.Info == SqlNotificationInfo.Invalid)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Accourd");
            }

            if (e.Info == SqlNotificationInfo.Isolation)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Isolation Accourd");
            }


            if (e.Info == SqlNotificationInfo.Merge)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Merge Accourd");
            }

            if (e.Info == SqlNotificationInfo.Options)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Options Accourd");


            }

            if (e.Info == SqlNotificationInfo.PreviousFire)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("PreviousFire Accourd");
            }

            if (e.Info == SqlNotificationInfo.Query)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Query Accourd");
            }

            if (e.Info == SqlNotificationInfo.Resource)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Resource Accourd");
            }

            if (e.Info == SqlNotificationInfo.Restart)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Restart Accourd");
            }

            if (e.Info == SqlNotificationInfo.TemplateLimit)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("TemplateLimit Accourd");
            }

            if (e.Info == SqlNotificationInfo.Truncate)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Truncate Accourd");
            }

            if (e.Info == SqlNotificationInfo.Unknown)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Unknown Accourd");
            }

            if (e.Info == SqlNotificationInfo.Update)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Update Accourd");
            }




        }

        private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            SqlDependency.Stop(connectionstring);
        }
    }
}
```

I grant all privillages to `sa` user with below statement:

```
grant all to sa
```

Note, that `SqlNotificationInfo.Options` occurs only, when application starts. And after that,  `SqlNotificationInfo` does not return anything. Anyone have any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

See *Set Option Settings* at [Creating a Query for Notifications](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181122%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

> When a SELECT statement is executed under a notification request, the connection that submits the request must have the options for the connection set as follows:
>
> - ANSI_NULLS ON
> - ANSI_PADDING ON
> - ANSI_WARNINGS ON
> - CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
> - QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
> - NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
> - ARITHABORT ON

When the documentation for [`SqlNotificationInfo.Query`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlnotificationinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documentation states the following, it is referring to the above list of `SET` options:

> The SET options were not set appropriately at subscription time.

The second database probably has some different options set by default at the database level. You can try changing the default database-wide `SET` options by issuing `SET <option> <value>` (e.g., `SET ANSI_NULLS ON`) commands. You might be able to run these in a separate SqlCommand on the the same SqlConnection object as your dependency is being created against. Or you could try editing the database’s default `SET` options via [SSMS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174173).